# Select and change property of all elements with css("color") of a certain value

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

How can I find all elements on a page which have a color of "blue"?

```
alert($("* [color=blue]").attr("id"));
```

The above example does not work. Please recognize that color is a CSS attribute. I'm certain it is possible I just cannot figure out the correct method to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $blueEles = $("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("color") == 'blue';
});
$blueEles.each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
$blueEles.hide();
// etc
```

Comment: For non-IE browsers this will not work. They all return `rgb(0,0,255)`